Typescript interface disjunction gives incorrect error
I have this function
export async function getPageProps(
    slug: string,
    variables: {
        [key: string]: any;
    } = {},
    appendResourcesToPage: Array<AppendedResource> = [],
): Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<PageProps>> 
{ ... }


These interfaces:
export interface PageProps {
    pageData: any;
    menus: {
        headerMenu: MenuItem[];
        footerMenu: MenuItem[];
        drawerMenu: MenuItem[];
        drawerFooterMenu: MenuItem[];
    };
    siteOptions: SiteOptions;
    globalSettings: GlobalSettingsQuery | null;
}

/**
 * The return type of `getStaticProps`.
 * @link https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#getstaticprops-return-values
 */
export type GetStaticPropsResult<Props> =
  | { props: Props; revalidate?: number | boolean }
  | { redirect: Redirect; revalidate?: number | boolean }
  | { notFound: true; revalidate?: number | boolean }

However when I try to use it, I get an error:
const commonSiteProps = await getPageProps('', {}, []) as GetStaticPropsResult<PageProps>;
const { siteOptions, globalSettings, menus } = commonSiteProps?.props || {};

And I can't figure out why
TS2339: Property props does not exist on type GetStaticPropsResult<PageProps>
Error remains even after:
const { siteOptions, globalSettings, menus } = (commonSiteProps as GetStaticPropsResult<PageProps>)?.props || {};


EDIT:
This fixes the issue, although it's not as nice as I had hoped
const commonSiteProps = await getPageProps('', {}, []);
let siteOptions, globalSettings, menus;
if (commonSiteProps && 'props' in commonSiteProps) {
    siteOptions = commonSiteProps?.props.siteOptions;
    globalSettings = commonSiteProps?.props.globalSettings;
    menus = commonSiteProps?.props.menus;
}
if (!siteOptions || !globalSettings || !menus) {
    throw new Error('Invalid page props.');
}


Have you searched for “union” (not “disjunction”) and “optional chaining”? That’s what I’ll do when I get off mobile and see if I can find a question this duplicates.

@jcalz it seems that I have to hint Typescript with a ('prop' in X), I had hopes that the as would help, but no. I had to implement the in thing which is more verbose and ugly... but works
